# checking and upgrade cURL version on windows server 2008R2

Tags: php, windows-server-2008, plesk

How to check whether cURL is installed on Windows Server 2008R2, check current version and how to upgrade to the latest version? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

*Please note: these are generic instructions and not specific to Windows Server. Furthermore, PHP and (to the best of my knowledge) Plesk currently use the version of cURL registered with the OS.*

---

> How do I check whether cURL is installed? How do I check the version?

If cURL is registered at the command line, you should be able to use `where curl` to determine the location of `curl.exe` (the Windows [where](https://ss64.com/nt/where.html) command is similar to `which` on *nix-style systems). You can also use `curl -V` to check your cURL version.

If these commands fail, you will (optionally) have to check your installed software, make a search of your hard drive for `curl.exe` or use other means to confirm if cURL is actually installed.

> How do I upgrade to the latest version of cURL?

Typically, you will want to remove the old version and replace it with a compatible Win32 or Win64 version of cURL from the [official cURL download page](https://curl.se/download.html).

<strike>Personally, I might suggest the builds by Viktor Szakats (he builds the latest versions frequently and often has a good amount of features enabled). You need to click on the blue revision number link (e.g. `7.59.0`) if you wish to download the actual curl `.zip` file (or whatever). Author name links often lead to unrelated pages.</strike>

*Update:*

The Viktor Szakats builds seem to have been supplanted by the [official builds of cURL for Windows](https://curl.se/windows/) (which are good and still recommended).

*Caveats*

- Not all builds on the cURL download page have all the same features enabled. You can check build options with `curl -V` (they are listed in the banner information) if you need to confirm support for a specific option/protocol.
- You may need to register your new cURL installation folder (*ex*. `C:\path\to\cURL`) in your Windows `Path` variable to allow cURL to be used from the command line.